# Sumar columna de varias tablas

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy intentando sumar los valores de la columna 4 de cinco tablas, pero no se como obtener su id, este es el código que tengo hasta ahora.

```
var sum= 0;
$("table tbody tr").each(function(){
    var suma=$(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
    console.log(suma);
        sum += parseFloat(suma);
            });
    console.log(sum);
```

El código me suma todos los valores de las columnas de todas las tablas, no se si sea posible que en este fragmento:

```
$("#idTabla tbody tr").each(function(){ 
    var suma=$(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
    console.log(suma);
        sum += parseFloat(suma);
            });
    console.log(sum);
```

El id de la tabla vaya el nombre de cada tabla y vaya sumando los valores de la columna cuatro, de las cinco tablas y lo devuelva individual, pero no quiero repetir el mismo código por las cinco tablas, ¿Cómo podría hacer esto por las cinco?, sería con un ciclo?, cualquier ayuda la agradecería infinitamente 
Gracias por su atención

Así están las cinco tablas en el html, cada una con un id diferente:

```html
<table id="Tabla1" class="table table-striped table-bordered  table-responsive my-0">

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Valor 1</th>
            <th>Valor 2</th>
            <th>Valor 3</th>
            <th>Valor 4</th>
            <th>Valor 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="PastoA">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>
                90
            </td>
            <td>70000</td>
      </tr>
      
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir un ejemplo de las tablas que intentas sumar?

Comment: Deberias agregar el HTML de las 5 tablas que quieres sumar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crearte una función en la cual pasas una serie de id de tus tablas a las que quieres obtener la suma de la cuarta columna.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  sumar4taCol(["#tabla1", "#tabla2", "#tabla3"]);
});

function sumar4taCol(idTable)
{
  $.each(idTable, function(index, value) {
    var suma = 0;
    $(value + " tbody tr").each(function() {
      suma += parseFloat($('td', this).eq(3).text());
    });
    console.log(value + ": " + suma);
  });
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Tabla 1</h3>
<table id="tabla1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>... 2</th>
      <th>... 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 

<h3>Tabla 2</h3>
 <table id="tabla2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>... 2</th>
      <th>... 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 

<h3>Tabla 3</h3>
 <table id="tabla3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>... 2</th>
      <th>... 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

La función lo que hace es recorrer cada uno de los id de tablas ingresados e ir a buscar y recorrer todos los `tr` y con `$('td', this).eq(3)` seleccionamos la cuarta columna de la fila actual recorrida. El índice es un `3` porque la 4ta columna se encuentra en ese índice.

Espero te pueda servir o modifiques el código a lo que necesitas.

> [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/): Dado un objeto jQuery que representa un conjunto de elementos DOM, el método .eq () construye un nuevo objeto jQuery a partir de un elemento dentro de ese conjunto. El índice suministrado identifica la posición de este elemento en el conjunto.

Comment: Muchas gracias Orlando De La Rosa era justamente lo que estaba buscando!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un array de sumas y hacer 2 bucles anidados para hacer la sumas.  Algo asi:

```
var sum= [];
$("table tbody").each(function(i, body){
    $(body).find('tr').each(function(){
        var suma=$(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
        console.log(suma);
        sum[i] += parseFloat(suma);
    });
    console.log(sum[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes colocarle una clase a los labels que quieras sumar class = "suma" y solo sumar los montos que le colocaste esta clase.

```
$(function(){   

  //funcion suma todo

  var sum = 0;
  $('.suma').each(function(x,y){
     sum += parseInt($(this).text());                                   
  })           
  $('#lblTotal').text(sum);   

});
```